# Kerberos Double Hop and Impersonate calls

Tags: c++, windows, security, kerberos, windowsdomainaccount

I have misunderstanding, I have code:

```
LogonUser(name,domain, password,LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,&hToken);
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hToken);
```

and later I do sspi connection with current user to my server(another PC)
**ImpersonateLoggedOnUser**--is it first hop?
How many hops I have:
1-connect to server(server thread impersonated to user)
2-logon->impersonate(1 hop)->connect to server(server thread impersonated to user)

Comment: The impersonation happens on the local machine, it shouldn't count as a "hop".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to change LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK to LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE :-(
and first impersonatewithloggeduser works like not hope(unclear why)